# Convert JSon in to Required Json Formate

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have an issue in converting JSON into required format any help would be appreciated Hope Some One can Help

Here is my Raw JSON result:

```
   //for Time being I have given a single object here, in the same way, I would get 2 more objects in the same JSON response

   OrderedDict([(u'totalSize', 3), (u'done', True), (u'records', 
   [OrderedDict([(u'attributes', OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Site'),
    (u'url', u'/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Site/0DM30000000CaYgGAK')])), 
    (u'Name', u'Renewals_Community1'), (u'DailyBandwidthLimit', 40960), 
   (u'DailyBandwidthUsed', 0.0), (u'DailyRequestTimeLimit', 3600), 
   (u'DailyRequestTimeUsed', 0.0), (u'MonthlyPageViewsEntitlement', 0)]),
```

Required JSon Formate:

```
           {
            "DailyBandwidthLimit":
             {
              "Max"://here my own value which is standard
              "Remaining":"40960"//(u'DailyBandwidthLimit', 40960), 
             }
           }
```

USed Methods to convert:

Written a for loop to print only the Required data

```
      for i in rs['records']:  
    printi['DailyBandwidthLimit']
    ///because of less space I am not placing  all the code
```

here I am able to get required fields but unable to form the JSON  Tried different options like printing data to file as json.dumps & again fetching data from a file using JSON.loads nothing seems to work well

```
 Finally
 data[] 
 data['Max'] = 8
 data['Remainig']= d
 data['DailyBandwidthLimit'] = [""]
 json_data = json.dumps(data)
 print  json_data
```

It came to some extent but I am unable to make required JSON

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

data=dict()
data['DailyBandwidthLimit'] = dict()
data['DailyBandwidthLimit']['Max'] = 8
data['DailyBandwidthLimit']['Remaining'] = 40960

json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

to print json_data on screen:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```